# PDF Form Field filler for Xamarin

Tags: pdf, xamarin, pdf-form

I've got an existing Xamarin Forms app and I'd like to add the functionality of filling out an existing PDF that contains Form Fields. I'd like to find an API that's either free or has a one time flat fee. I'd like to have one that's compatible with Xamarin, but if that's not available, I could work with something that runs on a server. I've got a very light PHP back end where I could add this functionality, too.

- I've seen [PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com/) that would probably do exactly what I want, but it's $4,500 USD per year, which is WAY out of budget.
- [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/) looks like it might be around $1,000 USD per year, which is still pretty high for my needs.

Are there other options I should be looking at?

Comment: Do you need a viewer control for filling form fields (let the user fill the fields interactively) or you want to fill the fields from code?

Comment: I'd like to fill the fields from code. I don't need to show the filled in PDF in the app. The user will be able to use that file externally once it's filled in.

Answer (score 0):

The [SetaPDF-FormFiller](https://www.setasign.com/formfiller) component (one of our products) has a one time flat fee including access to updates for one year which can be renewed anually for 20% of the license fee or on a lower fee in advance. An overview of licenses and pricing is available [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/pricing/).

It allows you to fill in PDF forms in pure **PHP**:

```
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('result.pdf');
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('form.pdf', $writer);

$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
$fields = $formFiller->getFields($fields);

$fields->get('Name')->setValue('John Doe');
$fields->get('Accepted')->check();
// ...

$document->save()->finish();
```

There are several [online demos](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/demos/) available on our website. The manual and API documentation can be found [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-formfiller-manual/).

Feel free to request an evaluation version to try things out your own [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/evaluate/).